# Color highlighting with soul package does not work well with ligatures

Tags: soul

The picture below says it all. Color highlighting with the `soul` package prevents a correct rendering of the `ff` ligature. Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, soul}
\begin{document}
off -- offer \hl{off -- offer}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

cfr's [answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236829/9077) demonstrates that the problem disappears if the words are boxed with `\mbox`. This will, however, break hyphenation and line-breaking, features that I would like to retain.

Comment: You could just box the individual words. That would break hyphenation, but not line-breaking, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Boxing the text to be highlighted avoids the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, soul}
\begin{document}
  off -- offer \hl{\mbox{off -- offer}}
\end{document}
```

[image: boxed highlighted text]

Comment: But the only reason I'm using `soul`'s `\hl` command over `color`'s `\colorbox` command is that the former allows line breaks. `\mbox` would take that function away again `:(`

Comment: @Sverre Well, you didn't say that in the question!

Comment: I know, but it's hard to predict in advance that the proposed solution will destroy something else in your document. I prefer to ask simple questions rather than say "here is a problem I have, and here are a thousand other things I do in my document that anyone trying to solve my problem will need to consider" `:)`

Comment: @Sverre Fair enough. I'm not complaining. Just that you have to expect that answers may not always solve the actual problem in that case, since it is impossible to guess what additional desiderata you may have in mind :).

Comment: For sure - I am always aware of that possible problem. But I prefer to deal with that problem when and if it arises. So I'll edit the question accordingly now.

Comment: Yeah I'm also looking for a solution, unfortunately this doesn't allow line breaks